# Windows 8, Firefox browser issues with Three.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js, mozilla

[image]

I got problem like image ONLY with Firefox Browser 27.0.1 Windows 8 with some example like loader/obj, 
loader/obj/mtl but not with "loader/scene", here the [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnjFMzJiLuc&feature=youtu.be).

So this is Firefox bug or Three.js problem? (videocard maybe,i'm using gtx675m) Anyway to fix this?